# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, exception

I am getting an error when my script executes the `except` block:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py", line 68, in create_user
    self.status_label.config(text='Failed to add user %s' % username)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment
```

It seems to me that `username` is local to the try block only.

```
def create_user(self):
    try:
        username = self.add_user(self.username_entry2.get(), self.password_entry2.get())
        self.status_label.config(text='Added user %s' % username)
    except Exception:
        self.status_label.config(text='Failed to add user %s' % username)
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Can't use `username` in the `except` block if it isn't assigned.

Comment: If the `self.add_user()` or either of the two `.get()` calls call raise an exception, `username` is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the variable `username` is local to the `try` block. But in your case there's no garantuee that the `username` is set when it goes into the `except` block.

For example:

```
try:
    username = 'a'
    raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
    print(username)
```

prints `a` because the exception was raised after `username` was defined. But in your case it seems the exception is raised before `username` was defined. So it's roughly like this:

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
    username = 'a'
except ValueError:
    print(username)
```

which would give a `NameError` (if the `try` and `except` are in a global scope) or an `UnboundLocalError` (if it's in a function).

That's the reason why you should make sure that the `try`-block **only contains the code that is "allowed to fail"**.

For example if you know that `self.username_entry2.get()` and `self.password_entry2.get()` cannot (or shouldn't) fail you could use:

```
def create_user(self):
    username_tmp = self.username_entry2.get()
    password_tmp = self.password_entry2.get()
    try:
        username = self.add_user(username_tmp, password_tmp)
    except Exception:
        self.status_label.config(text='Failed to add user %s' % username_tmp)
    else:
        self.status_label.config(text='Added user %s' % username)
```

The `else` block is only executed if the `try` passed. That's another way to limit the code in the `try`-block.